# How do I put all the answers in a list? Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-api, telebot

I have a problem. I want the bot to wait for an answer after each question and then write it down in the list

And yes, I understand what I'm doing absolutely wrong in this code, but I cut out all my attempts and inserted "Clean Code" here to convey the idea. Please help!!

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["channel_boss"])
def channel(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        data_for_BossChannel = []

        TokenName = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Введите имя токена:\n(например BTCUCDT)")
        data_for_BossChannel.append(TokenName)

        Money = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Введите кол-во долларов:\n(например 250)")
            
        data_for_BossChannel.append(Money)


        Shoulder = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Введите плечо:\n(например 25)")
            
        data_for_BossChannel.append(Shoulder)


        StartPlace = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Введите цену входа:\n(например 30000)")
            
        data_for_BossChannel.append(StartPlace)


        LongOrShort = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Выберите позицию:")

        data_for_BossChannel.append(LongOrShort)
```

I tried using if else, next_step_handler with an empty function, and so on